# Jenkins: Retrieve a variable from json file and use it after

Tags: json, jenkins

I have a issue on jenkins. I make a http request and this return me a json file like this:

```
httpRequest authentication: 'b689fe3c-117e-4076-b10d-fe16ab14742f', httpMode: 'POST', outputFile: 'merge.json', responseHandle: 'NONE', url:'http://address:port/prweb/api/v1/branches/TestB/merge'


{  "ID": "SYSTEM-QUEUE-MERGE 50304628545400035CA951969013040610A435733ECEAE8",
 "pxObjClass": "Pega-API-CI-Branch",
 "statusValue": "OK"
}
```

I want the ID to use in a other http request:

```
http://address:port/prweb/api/v1/merges/{$ID}
```

I try to catch the Id like this: ID=$(cat merge.json |grep -o SY.*[a-z] (all json file are the same)

I try to catch the ID in a sh pipe but he doesn't work, so I tried to define on the step, same as before. If someone had the solution, it'll be great for me!
I continue to search and I'll edit if I suceed

Edit: the code of my pipe:

```
pipeline{
agent any
stages{
    stage ('Merge Branch') {

        steps{

            httpRequest authentication: 'b689fe3c-117e-4076-b10d-fe16ab14742f', httpMode: 'POST', outputFile: 'merge.json', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: 'http://address:port/prweb/api/v1/branches/TestB/merge'

            httpRequest authentication: 'b689fe3c-117e-4076-b10d-fe16ab14742f', httpMode: 'GET', outputFile: 'merge3.json', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: 'http://address:port/prweb/api/v1/merges/'

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: _like this_? like what? Also show the code

Comment: "Talk is cheap, show me the code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that grep doesn't work for me. i'm sure you could get it working with enough messing around.

if you install jq, you can do the following:

```
ID="$(cat merge.json | jq -r .ID)"

# produces SYSTEM-QUEUE-MERGE 50304628545400035CA951969013040610A435733ECEAE8 
# as expected
echo "$ID"
```

of course even when you successfully get the output parsed by the shell, then you would still need to get the result back into the groovy context in order to use `httpRequest`. a hot solution is avoiding `httpRequest` entirely and just using curl for the three requests. :) this approach (using external scripts for your builds) is, perhaps unintuitively, advocated by the jenkins folks.

if you *must* keep the http requests in groovy, here is a full pipeline that answers your question:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        script {
          def idFromJson = sh(script: "cat merge.json | jq -r .ID", returnStdout: true).trim()

          # produces output: idFromJson: SYSTEM-QUEUE-MERGE 50304628545400035CA951969013040610A435733ECEAE8
          echo "idFromJson: ${idFromJson}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I already try jq and it didn't work. I have the SYSTEM[] as expected but my problem is what you saying after. I don't know how to get the result in the current context. (Curl doesn't work too)

Comment: if you put all of the curls outside of the groovy context, you don't need to be in the groovy context at all. but i updated the answer to show how you can get the results back to the groovy context if you want to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way would be to use the [readJson](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readjson-code-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) plugin from jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline{
agent any
stages{
stage ('Merge Branch') {

    steps{

        httpRequest authentication: 'b689fe3c-117e-4076-b10d-fe16ab14742f', httpMode: 'POST', outputFile: 'merge.json', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: 'http://address:port/prweb/api/v1/branches/TestB/merge'
        def jsonResponse = readJSON file: 'merge.json'

        httpRequest authentication: 'b689fe3c-117e-4076-b10d-fe16ab14742f', httpMode: 'GET', outputFile: 'merge3.json', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: "http://address:port/prweb/api/v1/merges/${jsonResponse.ID}"

    }
}
}
```

you can alternatively read the response content rather than saving to a file:

```
pipeline{
agent any
stages{
stage ('Merge Branch') {

    steps{

        def response = httpRequest authentication: 'b689fe3c-117e-4076-b10d-fe16ab14742f', httpMode: 'POST', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: 'http://address:port/prweb/api/v1/branches/TestB/merge'
        def jsonResponse = readJSON text: "${response.content}"

        httpRequest authentication: 'b689fe3c-117e-4076-b10d-fe16ab14742f', httpMode: 'GET', outputFile: 'merge3.json', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: "http://address:port/prweb/api/v1/merges/${jsonResponse.ID}"
    }
}
}
```